# Application freezes on futex() call

Tags: haskell, freeze

I have microservice written in Haskell. It uses Scotty. LTS is 13.20. OS: Linux 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64, it works under Kubernetes. The service worked about 0.5 year without problems but now I hit several times some mysterious freezing. I think it is not a result of a regression, because the code was not modified, but the loading on service was increased.

The symptoms are:

- CPU consumption - OK
- Memory consumption - OK
- `strace` reports freezing on futex(...) call: `futex(0x349c9c4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 83, NULL`
- a lot of threads which look like:

```
F S   UID   PID  SPID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0     1     1     0  0  80   0 -   274 do_sig ?        00:00:00 myinit
4 S     0     6     6     1  0  80   0 -  2922 do_wai ?        00:00:00 rc.init
4 S     0    32    32     0  0  80   0 -  2955 do_wai pts/0    00:00:00 bash
4 S     0  4464  4464     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service
1 S     0  4464  4465     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4466     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4467     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4468     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4469     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4470     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4471     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4472     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 timerf ?    00:00:00 ghc_ticker
1 S     0  4464  4473     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 ep_pol ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4474     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 poll_s ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4475     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4476     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4477     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4478     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4479     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4480     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4481     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4482     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4483     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4484     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service
1 S     0  4464  4485     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service
1 S     0  4464  4486     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
1 S     0  4464  4487     6  0  80   0 - 268854048 futex_ ?    00:00:00 my-service:w
0 R     0  4511  4511    32  0  80   0 - 12405 -      pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

After attachment to the PID with `gdb`:

```
[New LWP 4487]
[New LWP 4486]
[New LWP 4485]
[New LWP 4484]
[New LWP 4483]
[New LWP 4482]
[New LWP 4481]
[New LWP 4480]
[New LWP 4479]
[New LWP 4478]
[New LWP 4477]
[New LWP 4476]
[New LWP 4475]
[New LWP 4474]
[New LWP 4473]
[New LWP 4472]
[New LWP 4471]
[New LWP 4470]
[New LWP 4469]
[New LWP 4468]
[New LWP 4467]
[New LWP 4466]
[New LWP 4465]
....
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007fc03ec23965 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00000000015185e9 in waitCondition (pCond=pCond@entry=0x2f029c0, pMut=pMut@entry=0x2f029f0) at rts/posix/OSThreads.c:117
No locals.
#2  0x000000000150713b in waitForWorkerCapability (task=<optimized out>) at rts/Capability.c:651
        cap = <optimized out>
#3  yieldCapability (pCap=pCap@entry=0x7fffc6ae0a78, task=task@entry=0x2f029b0, gcAllowed=gcAllowed@entry=true) at rts/Capability.c:888
        cap = <optimized out>
#4  0x0000000001504d85 in scheduleYield (task=0x2f029b0, pcap=0x7fffc6ae0a70) at rts/Schedule.c:672
        cap = 0x2e7cff0
        didGcLast = <optimized out>
#5  schedule (initialCapability=initialCapability@entry=0x2edf1b0, task=task@entry=0x2f029b0) at rts/Schedule.c:292
        t = <optimized out>
        cap = 0x2e7cff0
        ret = <optimized out>
        prev_what_next = <optimized out>
        ready_to_gc = <optimized out>
#6  0x0000000001505bee in scheduleWaitThread (tso=0x4200823388, ret=ret@entry=0x0, pcap=pcap@entry=0x7fffc6ae0b08) at rts/Schedule.c:2533
        task = 0x2f029b0
        cap = 0x2edf1b0
#7  0x0000000001500584 in rts_evalLazyIO (cap=cap@entry=0x7fffc6ae0b08, p=p@entry=0x15a00d0, ret=ret@entry=0x0) at rts/RtsAPI.c:530
        tso = <optimized out>
#8  0x00000000015102be in hs_main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffc6ae0cf8, main_closure=0x15a00d0, rts_config=...) at rts/RtsMain.c:72
        cap = 0x2edf1b0
        exit_status = <optimized out>
        status = <optimized out>
#9  0x00000000004311b0 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

So, my questions are: how to fix it, investigate, what would be good to try, to check? I had idea to switch to new LTS, but I am not sure that it's the reason of the problem (I found similar problems with old LTS/GHC versions in Web forums)... IMHO it looks like a bug in RTS.

Comment: Were you able to discover what was causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually workers wait on the condition in `waitForWorkerCapability` when there is no work to do. E.g. all haskell threads are blocked on IO, so we don't have anything to run. The condition is signaled in [giveCapabilityToTask](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/30be3bf13a6e72247ff561df1f291370dad79ef9/rts/Capability.c#L495), it's called in few places in the same file.

If you are sure there should be work to do, then you probably found a bug in RTS. Try to come with a minimal example that reproduces the issue. (I know, it's often not possible at all.)

But there could be a bug in your code or dependencies. You can try to inspect [capabilities](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/30be3bf13a6e72247ff561df1f291370dad79ef9/rts/Capability.h#L30) in gdb. (There is a [global array](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/30be3bf13a6e72247ff561df1f291370dad79ef9/rts/Capability.c#L50) on them). You might be interested in `running_task`, `run_queue_hd`, `suspended_ccalls`, `spare_workers`, `returning_tasks_hd` fields. I think you should have no running task and empty ran queue on all capabilities, and all workers should be in the `spare_workers` list of some capability.

(That's just my understanding of the issue. I'm not an expert in GHC RTS, and probably saying nonsense.)